# processing json file, how to access the array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following json file

```
{ "people" : [
    {
    name: "ada,",
    age: "23",
    params : {}
    }, 
    {
    name: "james",
    call : "24",
    params : {}
    }
]}
```

Im using the html 5 file reader, to read the file

```
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {       
          //var objectArray = JSON.stringify(reader.result);
          //var objectArray2 = JSON.parse(objectArray);
          for (var i=0; i<reader.result.length; i++) {
                for (j in reader.result[i]) {
                    //access each piece of infomration

                };
            }                 

      };
    })(f);

    reader.readAsText(f);
```

I have tried stringfy and parse and nothing seems to help me be able to extract the data out of the json file. If i use any index I just get the first character in the file rather than the object.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: That JSON won't parse. It's invalid.

Comment: Try your json file in [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file isn't JSON.  Add quotes around the key names like this:

```
{ "people" : [
    {
    "name": "ada,",
    "age": "23",
    "params" : {}
    }, 
    {
    "name": "james",
    "call" : "24",
    "params" : {}
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON isn't valid dude. You need to wrap the keynames in " " as well as the strings.